# Not able to connect to TNS enty in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, tnsnames

I have oracle sql server installed in my machine but it is not able to read all tns entries when creating new connection , it only shows one entry.I also tried to set the tnsnames.ora path explicitly in preference but then too it only reads one entry whereas I have a lot more connections in my tnsnames.ora file?

Comment: Do you have multiple Oracle Homes?

Answer (score 0):

Use the netmgr utility in $ORACLE_HOME/bin directory to add database entries. It will make sure the new entries are added to the correct tnsnames.ora file